# After migrating to Visual Studio 2015 constructor .create missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, automapper, global-asax, func

I installed `Visual Studio 2015 Community` and I tried to open two projects here the first worked perfectly, but the second showed the following error in `Global.asax.cs`
[image]

The error can be seen below:
[image]

For some reason it is not finding the `.Create` method. But if I open the same project in `Visual Studio 2013` it works with no errors.

I use `.Net Framework 4.5`
The methods look like using `OData.Entities`

The code below is the class `.AddressMapper()`

```
public class AddressMapper : TimestampMapper, IMapper<AccountCustomerEntity, Address>
{
    public AddressMapper();  
    public void Map(AccountCustomerEntity accountCustomerEntity, Address address);
}
```

The codes below show the method: `.WithAddressFn` and parents.

```
public static class OrderMapperExtensions
{
    public static OrderMapper WithAccountFn(this OrderMapper mapper, Func<int, Account> accountFn);
    public static OrderMapper WithAddressFn(this OrderMapper mapper, Func<AccountCustomerEntity, Address> addressFn);
    public static OrderMapper WithArticleFn(this OrderMapper mapper, Func<RequisitionDeliveryDetailEntity, Article> articleFn);
    public static OrderMapper WithCarrierFn(this OrderMapper mapper, Func<int, Carrier> carrierFn);
    public static OrderMapper WithLineItemFn(this OrderMapper mapper, Func<RequisitionLineEntity, LineItem> lineItemFn);
    public static OrderMapper WithStatusFn(this OrderMapper mapper, Func<short, Status> statusFn);
    public static OrderMapper WithTransactionFn(this OrderMapper mapper, Func<IEnumerable<TransactionEntity>, Transaction> transactionFn);
    public static OrderMapper WithUserFn(this OrderMapper mapper, Func<string, User> userFn);
}

public class OrderMapper : TimestampMapper, IMapper<RequisitionEntity, Order>
{
    public Func<int, Account> AccountFn;
    public Func<AccountCustomerEntity, Address> AddressFn;
    public Func<RequisitionDeliveryDetailEntity, Article> ArticleFn;
    public Func<int, Carrier> CarrierFn;
    public Func<RequisitionLineEntity, LineItem> LineItemFn;
    public Func<short, Status> StatusFn;
    public Func<IEnumerable<TransactionEntity>, Transaction> TransactionFn;

    public OrderMapper();

    public void Map(RequisitionEntity requisitionEntity, Order order);
}
```

Is anyone able to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been through several problems when I changed my IDE to 2015, Follow these links this might be helpful for you [MSDN 2015 Guide 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx) and [Guide 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn762121.aspx) Hope that will help you.